# Sort within a pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas groupby that results in the below group (with the third column being the % of the total observations).

I would like to sort the second column by the third column, such that the "0-20" group would start with high school, then no high school, then some college, etc, and then the "80-90" group would start with a BA Degree, then graduate degree, etc.

In other words, I want to sort the educ_name field within each income_name field by the third column. However, I can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
income_name  educ_name
0-20         Assoc Degree       11.0
             BA Degree           9.0
             Graduate Degree     3.0
             High school        33.0
             No High School     26.0
             Some College       17.0
20-40        Assoc Degree       13.0
             BA Degree          13.0
             Graduate Degree     5.0
             High school        33.0
             No High School     19.0
             Some College       17.0
40-60        Assoc Degree       12.0
             BA Degree          19.0
             Graduate Degree     9.0
             High school        30.0
             No High School     11.0
             Some College       19.0
60-80        Assoc Degree       14.0
             BA Degree          27.0
             Graduate Degree    15.0
             High school        24.0
             No High School      5.0
             Some College       16.0
80-90        Assoc Degree       12.0
             BA Degree          35.0
             Graduate Degree    26.0
             High school        13.0
             No High School      2.0
             Some College       12.0
90-100       Assoc Degree        6.0
             BA Degree          39.0
             Graduate Degree    39.0
             High school         7.0
             No High School      3.0
             Some College        6.0
```

Comment: `df.sort_values(['income_name','third column','educ_name'])`?

Comment: Well you don't  have 3 columns. You have a Series with a MultiIndex with 2 levels. Unfortunately the `sort` functions either operate on the index **or** the columns, not across both. So you can `reset_index` then sort and `set_index` back. Though there's probably a better way.

Comment: @Jake, your result is coming from something like `df.groupby(['income_name', 'educ_name']).size()` right? If that's the case it sorts the keys. If instead you did `df.groupby('income_name')['educ_name'].value_counts()` you'd get the sorting you want.

Comment: It would be good to have a code snippet to reproduce part of that data, that would make testing potential answers way quicker.